# Placing grouped points on a 2d grid in different variations

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Let's say I'm working on a grid of binary values like so:

```
  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  
  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

I have a set of "shapes" made up of 1s, that I want to place on this grid, without overlapping each other or the other 1s on the grid:

```
  1  1     1           
           1  1     1
```

I'm aiming to write a function which can generate different variations of the shape placements that follow these rules (possibly by inputting a seed). The shapes would ideally be placed in a way which feels visually imprecise or messy.

My first idea for how to approach this was to loop through each shape, and use a pseudo-random number generator to pick a position on the grid, then check whether the shape would fit at this position. If it does, place it there. If not, repeat the process until a fit is found.

But is there a more elegant and reliable algorithmic approach that I can use to achieve this?

I've seen a few past questions dealing with similar problems, but they were all either contingent on specific details or had unclear answers, so I'm hoping you all can provide me with some more tailored advice. Thank you.

Comment: What have you done? share your code

Comment: For a sparsely populated grid, and a few small shapes, the random approach that you described will work well. If the total number of 1s (initial 1s plus the number of 1s in the shapes) is close to the total number of positions in the grid, the problem becomes similar to an [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).

Comment: What is your metric for deciding it is efficient enough? For which input you have a problem with performance?

Comment: Randomly placing the elements is much worse than brute force. Brute force means you try all possible combinations in a specific order. There is nothing random in brute force. Backtracking or dynamic programming should be much better than brute force.

Comment: Why would you use the terms "random" and "brute force" in combination with backtracking? [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). I would also ask this question at https://math.stackexchange.com. They're usually better at problem-solving using algorithms. This platform works better for programming question related to specific programming questions.

Comment: If you don't understand the Wiki page, what do you expect from the answer? A whole book as an answer? I recommend a good book about algorithms. It took me multiple days of reading and practicing to understand dynamic programming.

Comment: Nico, you say, "...picking random spots to place them <each shape> until it finds somewhere they fit?". Exactly how will you do that and what is your argument that such a procedure would place shapes in a *random* way? Please see my comment above for a discussion of "randomness" in this context.

Comment: I think the word "random" should be removed from this question. It's not what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the task can be seen as (simplified) [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression): You may see the grid as a long string (concatenate all lines) in which you search for an empty space of the given shape.

For example, if you look for a shape:

```
 11
  11
```

then the regexp is something like:

```
00............00
```

`0` corresponds to the `1` of the shape (you're looking for an empty space in the grid), the number of `.` (in standard regexp notation `.` denotes *any* character) in the regexp here corresponds to the gap between second `1` on the 1st line and first `1` of the 2nd line of the shape (you need to take width of the grid into account.)

So check some advanced string searching algorithms.

Comment: this is a really interesting way of framing/approaching the problem — you're saying for each new shape, use a string search algorithm to locate all the possible placements, and then pick one of them at random?

Comment: @Nico Solving a problem with randomness is probably the worst approach. This sounds like [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort). Use backtracking or dynamic programming to iterate all possible combinations.

Comment: This is a really novel and cool idea that may has other applications. It has nothing to do with finding a random non-interfering placement of a shape, but as @jabba has observed, the OP may not actually be concerned with randomness. You really should provide a good example with multiple lines. jabba, how does this differ from a backtracking approach?

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/0fVW4R/1) is an application of this idea. The grid is comprised of 4 rows (lines) in the "TEST STRING" section. The first row is '11000110000010111'. The zeroes are positions that can be occupied by the string; the ones are blocking characters. I've also shown a two-row shape, the rows being '0000..00' and '..00....00' if left-adjusted. Each dot indicates that a zero or one can be at that position. The regular expression is `(?s)0000..00............00....00`...

Comment: ...`(?s)` invokes single-line (or DOTALL) mode, causing periods to match any character, including line-termination characters. The portion of the regex following `(?s)` is the shape after being "flattened". It is seen that the flattened shape begins with the first row of the shape, ends with the last row of the shape and has `n` periods inserted in between, where `n` equals the difference between the length of each row of the grid, including the line terminator, less the length of the first row of the shape (not including a line terminator). It is seen where the regex matches the grid.

Answer (score 0):

We are given a m x n array `grid`, such as the following:

```
grid = [
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
]
```

Here `m = 4` and `n = 17`.

Now consider a shape:

```
shape = [
  [ 0,   0,  0, 0, ".", ".",  0,   0],
  [".", ".", 0, 0, ".", ".", ".", ".", 0, 0]
]
```

The elements `"."` indicate that a zero or one can be in the corresponding location in `grid`.

---

Next flatten `shape`:

```
flattened_shape = shape.first + 
                  ['.'] * (grid.first.size - shape.first.size) +
                  shape.last
  #=> [ 0,   0,   0,   0,  ".", ".",  0,   0,
  #    ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
  #    ".", ".",  0,   0,  ".", ".", ".", ".",  0,  0]
```

`flattened_shape` is an array that begins with the first row of `shape`, ends with the last row of `shape` and has `grid.first.size - shape.first.size = 17 - 8 = 9` strings, `"."` inserted in between.

If `shape` had a third row, `arr`, inserted between the first and second row `arr` would appear after the `9` `"."`'s and `grid.first.size - arr.size` `"."`'s would be inserted after `arr`. `flattend_shape` would be generated in this way for `shape` having any number of elements.

---

Next we flatten `grid`:

```
flattened_grid = grid.flatten
  #=> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
  #    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  #    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  #    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

---

We may now simply see if `flattened_shape` can be "slid along" `flattened_grid` to see if there is a fit. In pseudocode (Ruby):

```
flattened_shape_size = flattened_shape.size
  #=> 27
flattened_grid_size = flattened_grid.size
  #=> 68
nbr_flattended_grid_offsets = flattened_grid_size - flattened_shape_size + 1
  #=> 42
```

```
idx = (0..nbr_flattended_grid_offsets - 1).find do |i|
  grid_slice = flattened_grid[i, flattened_shape_size]
  flattened_shape.zip(grid_slice).all? do |s,g|
    s == "." || g == 0
  end
end 
  #=> 24
```

So a match has been found<sup>1</sup>. As `grid` has `17` "columns"

```
24/17 #=> 1
24.modulo(17) #=> 7
```

We therefore see that the shape begins in row offset `24/17 #=>1` (second row) and column offset `24.modulo(17) #=> 7` of `grid`. We can picture that as follows.

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, ., ., 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [., ., 0, 0, ., ., ., ., 0, 0]]
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

<sup>1. Note `[1, 2].zip([3, 4])` returns `[[1, 3], [2, 4]]`.</sup>